# How to route ElasticSearch to a specific node (not shard)?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I know it's possible to route a search to a specific shard, but I'm looking to route a search to a specific node. The reason is because some nodes are more powerful than others, and I want to have logic to hit those nodes more than the weaker nodes when conducting a query.

Is this possible? I know, short question but believe me I've done a lot of research and Googling and couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you will set an awareness attribute based on the class of machine, you can use it to [automatically route requests](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#_automatic_preference_when_searching_geting) within the class. If you are using java-based transport or node clients you can simply assign the same awareness attributes to your clients and they will automatically route request to the nodes with the same set of attributes. If you are using REST clients, you can either connect to machines of desired class or add dedicated client nodes into your cluster, assign them desired awareness attribute and use the to execute queries.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Just append this in the REST URL when searching "&preference=_primary_first"

Comment: You don't really have control over allocation of primary shards, so they can get allocated on weaker nodes.

Comment: That's true. I ended up just passing in the node ID for preference.